# Laravel 5.6 - Validation sending to index, not to previous page with errors

Tags: php, laravel-5.6

When submitting the form in register.blade.php, you are redirected back to the index rather than being brought back to the original page with errors displayed. I am not sure why this is.

The create method in the controller is called, but execution stops after the validation (as expected). There is no redirect back to the index there, so I am not sure why it's choosing to go back there. It's my understanding it defaults to redirecting back to the form with errors.

Routes:

```
<?php

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('pages.index');
});

Route::get('/home', function () {
    return redirect('/');
});

// Login //
Route::get('/user/login', function () {
    return view('pages.user.login');
});
Route::post('/user/login', 'UserController@store');

// Register //
Route::get('/user/register', function () {
    return view('pages.user.register');
});
Route::post('/user/register', 'UserController@create');
Route::post('/user/register', 'UserController@create');

// Logout //
Route::get('/user/logout', 'UserController@destroy');
```

register.blade.php

```
@extends ('layout.master')

@section ('content')

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h1 align="center">User Registration</h1>
        <br>
        <form method="POST" action="/user/register">

            {{ csrf_field() }}

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Full Name</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Full Name">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="phonenumber" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Phone Number</label>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <input name="phonenumber" type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Number">
                </div>

                <label for="password" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Password</label>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <input name="password" type="password" id="password" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Email</label>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
                </div>

                <label for="password_confirmation" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Confirm Password</label>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <input name="password_confirmation" type="password" id="password_confirmation" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="street_address" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Street Address</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input name="street_address" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Street Address">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="city" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">City / Town</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input name="city" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="City / Town">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="region" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">State / Province / Region</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input name="region" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="State / Province / Region">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="zip" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Postal Code</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input name="zip" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Postal Code">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="text-center">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary text-center">Submit</button>
            </div>

        </form>

        <br>

        @include('layout.errors')
    </div>
</div>

@endsection
```

errors.blade.php

```
@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    // Register
    public function create(Request $request)
    {
        // Form Validation
        $this->validate(request(), [
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
            'phonenumber' => 'required|regex:/^[0-9]{10}$/|unique:users',
            'street_address' => 'required',
            'city' => 'required',
            'region' => 'required',
            'zip' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed'
        ]);

        // Create and save the user.
        $user = User::create([
            'name' => request('name'),
            'email' => request('email'),
            'phonenumber' => request('phonenumber'),
            'street_address' => request('street_address'),
            'city' => request('city'),
            'state' => request('state'),
            'zip' => request('zip'),
            'password' => bcrypt(request('password'))
        ]);

        // Sign in the user.
        //auth()->login($user);

        return redirect('/test');
    }

    // Login
    public function store()
    {
        if (auth()->attempt(request(['email', 'password'])))
        {
            return redirect('/');
        } 
        else 
        {
            return Redirect::back()->withErrors(['Invalid email or password!']);
        }       
    }

    // Logout
    public function destroy()
    {
        auth()->logout();

        return redirect('/user/login');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the exact same issue. To elaborate on OP self-answer, this issue is caused by Firefox's 'network.http.referer.trimmingPolicy' config key which controls the sent 'Origin' header.

In my case this key was set to (int) 2, which makes the browser send only the address of the website without the URI.

Changing the key to (int) 0 solved the issue (one may try to set it to (int) 1).

Comment: 1 also working. See: https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Referrer

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with my Firefox config settings. There's a such thing as going TOO private...

Comment: I am using postman. but when I debug validator it bypass all thing and show my welcome page.

Answer (score 0):

For some people who might come across this. I had a `referrer` meta tag set up with the `content="origin"` policy.

This makes it so that the redirects will always refer to your 'origin'.

Change `<meta name="referrer" content="origin">` to `<meta name="referrer" content="origin-when-cross-origin">`

More info in this [article](https://www.sentinelstand.com/article/laravel-redirects-break-when-using-origin-referrer-policy).